# Rails configuration secret key base returning nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

When running rails console, my call to `Rails.configuration.secret_key_base` in my development environment keeps returning nil.

```
#secrets.yml

development:
  secret_key_base: the-long-secret-generated-by-rake-secret

#...other configs, a call while running heroku rails c in production also returns nil
```

How can this be? Running rails 4.1.0

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As noted in [the documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#config-secrets-yml):

> The secrets added to this file are accessible via `Rails.application.secrets`.

Running `Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base` from the console should return: `the-long-secret-generated-by-rake-secret`

Comment: Yes, errant on my part. I had read in another (not official) rails guide to call it this way. http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#config-secrets-yml